# How to add another dictionary in LaTeX/TeXnicCenter?

Tags: spelling, texniccenter, dictionaries

In the options menu in TexnicCenter you can go to the tab Spelling. There is the option to download a dictionary. I did that, but I still cannot choose this dictionary as default language. How can I change the language?

Comment: As shown below you can download the old OOo dictionaries. However, you might want to consider aspell. It works much better in my experience. Aspell is the GNU spellchecker and there is a windows version as well. Download aspell und a dictionary. You can add a tool to texniccenter to make it easier to run. Go to Tools->Customize->Tools and then have a look at the screenshot here: http://bit.ly/h52Ajv It is in german but pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 7):

You need to download the old language packages of OpenOffice

1. Goto [Dictionaries@OOo](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries)
2. Select your language
3. Find a download to a zip file (containing a *.aff and *.dic file)
4. Copy all that files into your %PROGRAM_FILES%/TeXnicCenter/Language

PS. Spell checking as nothing to do with LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

Another location to find dic files is [LibreOffice Dictionaries](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any&sort_on=created)

Like desribed by [speravir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9237/speravir) in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154262/167815)