# Installation of TeXnicCenter dictionary

Tags: texniccenter, spelling

I downloaded the Portuguese dictionary from OpenOffice repository. Following the instructions provided in the TeXnicCenter documentation, I moved the `.aff` and `.dic` files to the language folder of the TXC. However, it fails when I try to set it as the default language. Under `Options` -> `Spelling`, the option `pt-BR` is present and I select it as the dicionary to be used and click `OK`, but I receive the message:

> Cannot open: `C:\Users\user\Documents\TXCUserDicionary.dic` Creating empty personal dictionary.

I am using TeXnicCenter 2.02, 64-bits.

Can anyone guess what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 'fr' dic. I moved my "personal dictionary" file to a folder where I have the write/read rights (your problem ?), but also under version control (SVN), which allows me to share this file with TEX sources.

Tools\options\Spelling : You can change de 'Personal dictionary' folder

For exemple `D:\Applic\LatexDoc\share\TXCUserDictionary.dic`

Answer (score 1):

The ***dictionary***  files do *not* belong into the subfolder *`Language`*, but into the subfolder *`Dictionaries`* (the help file is wrong here!). The dictionary files are only for spelling corrections, *not* for the user interface of TeXnicCenter itself. You would need a DLL file (really!) suiting to your favorite language.

Instead of downloading from [Apache OpenOffice Dictionaries](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/de/search?f%5b0%5d=field_project_tags%3A157) you could also download from [LibreOffice Dictionaries](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary&getCompatibility=any&sort_on=created) *(in both cases do only extract with an archiver, the OXT files are actually zipped)*. If you already have installed one of these program suites you could also copy the needed files.

I got the error message frequently, too. So I created the empty file myself in this folder I set up in menu “Tools” —> “Options” —> tab “Spelling” —> “Personal”. I do not remember, if I’ve changed here anything or if I left the default setting untouched, because it is here `C:\Users\<my-username>\Documents\TXCUserDictionary.dic`. When your username is actually `user`, then I have the default setting, as well.

The program claims, it would create the file itself, but this does not happen. I would consider this a bug. But as far as I see, this was not reported until now in the bug tracker for TXC, see [TeXnicCenter / Bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/bugs/).

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary files belong into "Dictionaries" (as @Speravir notes) and must have the name LN_dialect.aff and LN_dialect.dic. LN is the two letter language code, dialect is any text. When there is a dash "-" instead of an underscore "_", the dictionary is not found.